# How to build an array of structs in Go and gRPC?

Tags: go, grpc

I am trying to add an array of strings into the content part of a struct with the Id as the array index. I have the code working for one element, but get various errors when I try and add the loop. Any ideas are welcome.  I am using Go.

```
func buildRequest(s []string) []*storepb.LongStoreRequest { 
//      ss:= []storepb.LongStoreRequest 
// int32 i =0 stringv := s[0] 
//      for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
    //              println(i, apps[i])
    ss := []*storepb.LongStoreRequest{
            &storepb.LongStoreRequest {
                    Msg: &storepb.StoreMessage{
                            Content: stringv,
                            Account:  "trevor3",
                            Parent: "parentrec",
                            Id: 0,
                    },
                    }, 
            } //      }
        return ss 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description correctly, you want to build an array of LongStoreRequests, where each element corresponding to an item in the string array, with Id giving the array index. If that's really what you need, something like this should work:

```
ss := []*storepb.LongStoreRequest{}
for i,str:=range s {
  ss=append(ss,&storepb.LongStoreRequest {
                  Msg: &storepb.StoreMessage{
                            Content: str,
                            Account:  "trevor3",
                            Parent: "parentrec",
                            Id: i,
                    }})
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Such a pleasure to see a professional at work.

Comment: @beserdar - can you vote up the question as someone downvoted it. I think this is due to an argument I had with someone who now seems to be following me downvoting everything I do.

Comment: @TrevorLeeOakley I don't get involved in these things. Try to phrase your questions better.

Comment: @bsedar -  how better? It is a piece of program code.

Comment: @TrevorLeeOakley what is the end result you need? What did you try and what errors did you get? "add an array of strings into the content part of struct" doesn't make much sense, but including the output you want would.

Comment: the output is fairly complex for this apps so I did not go into that. Hence I focused on the go part.